# Defining Nested Dictionaries in Swift

Tags: swift, dictionary

In the below code, I get an error `[String : Double] does not conform to Hashable`. How do i get around this?

I see the problem of non-conformance to Hashable protocol, but i'm wondering why this would be the case , that other way works. Is only 'Key' in a dictionary is required to confirm to Hashable? Some explanation would help

```
enum someEnumType {
    case First(String, (Int, Int)->Int)
    case Second (String, Int)
}
//    var operations = [someEnumType : [String : Double]]();  <--- This syntax Works

var operations = [[String : Double] : someEnumType  ]();  <--- But this does not work, ideally - i want this.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are correct, only a Dictionary's key must conform to the Hashable protocol.

### "How do I get around this?"

Probably the most direct way of using a Dictionary the way you want to is to define your own key type. A `struct` makes sense here; it offers the same value semantics that your `[String: Double]` would-be key offers, and it is easy to define:

```
struct MyKey {
    let myString: String
    let myDouble: Double
}
```

Of course, it must be hashable to be used as a Dictionary key, so we add `Hashable` conformance:

```
struct MyKey: Hashable {
    let myString: String
    let myDouble: Double

    var hashValue: Int {
        return self.myString.hashValue ^ self.myDouble.hashValue
    }
}
```

*I did a cute trick there to calculate a "unique-ish" hash value for this key type: just an XOR of the string's and double's hash values. I won't guarantee uniqueness, but it should be good enough for most cases. Calculating a better hash value is an exercise I'll leave up to you if you want (but it will work just fine like this).*

Finally, to conform to `Hashable`, one must also conform to `Equatable`. In our case we'll just check to see if each of a key's properties match the other's to determine if keys are equal. The full implementation:

```
struct MyKey: Hashable {
    let myString: String
    let myDouble: Double

    var hashValue: Int {
        return self.myString.hashValue ^ self.myDouble.hashValue
    }
}

func ==(lhs: MyKey, rhs: MyKey) -> Bool {
    return lhs.myString == rhs.myString && lhs.myDouble == rhs.myDouble
}
```

---

Now, you may define your Dictionary like this:

```
var operations = [MyKey : someEnumType  ]()
```

And add an entry like this:

```
let myFirstKey = MyKey(myString: "Hello", myDouble: 1.0)
operations[myFirstKey] = someEnumType
```

Answer (score 1):

Dictionaries are also called† hash tables; they work by hashing the key. So, yes, it does need to be `Hashable`. The value doesn't since the point is to look up values *by key*.

† Well, strictly speaking one could implement a dictionary without hashing, but in practice a data structure called a dictionary in programming languages is usually understood to be a hash map. In Swift as well, the `Dictionary` documentation specifies it as a “hash-based mapping”.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the key needs to be hashable.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to work around this by using NSString rather than String.